# Iterating over database columns and extracting specific values

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following df and want to extract the values marked below:

```
  0          0       0        
*141,902*    0       0       
  0          0       0      
  0         *140,927*0      
  0          0       0          
 114,2      150,213 *152,20*    
  0          0      *152,20*        
  0        139,682   0
```

**more elaboration**: take the values between the first two zeroes of each column.

```py
i=0
for key,value in df_specific.iteritems():
    if value[i]==0:
        i +=1
        if value[i]!=0:
            print(value[i])
            i += 1
            if value[i] == 0:
                break
                df_specific.index += 1
```

my code above worked , but only for the first column (not sure why), hence gave only the first value : ***141,9028*** . 
I believe that I only need a way to move directly to the next column.
any ideas?

Comment: Please, edit the question and paste the data in text format to reproduce it easily.

Comment: _I believe that I only need a way to move directly to the next column. any ideas?_ `iteritems()` is a generator that automatically moves to the next column on next loop

Comment: hey @AnkitAgrawal, i am aware of that.. but my code somehow only generates the first value

Comment: Check my answer you'll get the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for key,values in df_specific.iteritems():
    f = 0
    ff = 0
    label_list = list(values.index)
    for index,value in zip(label_list,list(values)):
        if value!=0 and f==0:
            print("index:"+index+"value:"+value)
            ff = 1
        if value == 0 and ff == 1:
            break
```

Comment: It actually did! thanks for the effort! I guess two counters did the job

Comment: Not only 2 counters; as I said `values` is the series and you need to also iterate through it what I did in my inner for loop

Comment: Hi Ankit, i have just deleted a comment, you could ignore it, there seemed to be a small bug from my side that was causing issues.your code is working just fine thanks!

Comment: I was trying to print some kind of a remark each time a new column is printed but I was not sure exactly where to insert it (tried different places in the loops), any idea?

Comment: Hello Ankit, quick question: I want to also print the row label of 'value' but I was not successful, could you help with it?

Comment: use the `key` variable of the loop, it iterates through the index(row label) of the dataframe

Comment: we're using iteritems, so **key** will return the column label. I tried an iterrows loop before yours but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Hey Ankit, I'm actually still kind of struggling to find a solution for it. any suggestions?

Comment: try using `values.index` it will give the`pandas.core.indexes.base.Index` type that can be accessed as a list in python and this will contain the row label of each row

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortuantely it didn't work also.

Comment: How did you use it? Did it not give you row lables?

Comment: i simply printed it : **print (values.index)** ,, it gave me a list rather than the index, or am i missing something?

Comment: As I told you it would give you a list of indexes which you can use inside inner for loop

Comment: true, but how would it know which label I want

Comment: yes it worked, it was very close to my answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 1], "B":[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1]})
df_ = (df == 0).cumsum() == 1
result = [df.loc[df_[col], col].values[1:] for col in df_.columns]
print(result)
# [array([0.5, 1. ]), array([1, 2, 3])]
```

This code would yield an error if there is a column where no solution is found, if this could occur, you could try :

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 1], "B":[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1]})
df_ = (df == 0).cumsum() == 1
result = [df.loc[df_[col], col].values[1:] 
          if df.loc[df_[col], col].size 
          else np.array([]) 
          for col in df_.columns if len(df.loc[df_[col], col].values)]
print(result)
# [array([0.5, 1. ]), array([1, 2, 3])]
```

If you would want to combine the results in one vector , you could do :

```
from itertools import chain 
res = [*chain.from_iterable(result),]
print(res)
# [0.5, 1.0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Or

```
res = [x for for l in result x in l ]
print(res)
# [0.5, 1.0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: thanks @AyoubZAROU!,  it was actually done in a more simple way by @Ankit Agrawal

Comment: Ow ok , it depends thought on what you prefer a simple solution or a fast one , it seems you prefer the simple one maybe because you don’t have a large set of data

Comment: thanks for the work @AyoubZAROU, i'm actually getting an Indexing error while implementing : NotImplementedError: Indexing a MultiIndex with a DataFrame key is not implemented